# use WCF service By ( windows form and android ) client

Tags: java, c#, wcf, security, role

At first I will describe my Current project and then ask Question.
1- Implementation Methodology : I developed project in WCF service on server side and have windows form and android client. I'm using dot net 3.5 and WebServiceHost and WebHttpBinding on server. android client developed on java  and connect to server by , on the other hand I have windows form and used channelfactory for connect to server.

2- authentication :authentication  is a little complex on my project. 
I have Item that name is workspace. each workspace can has several role. 
user can related to several workspace. Currently I'm sending username, password and workspaceid to server by each method from Clinet( winform and android).

Questions:

1- I Know by WCF authorization I can send username and password to server from windows form with channelfactory by How can I Implement Role-based or Idendity-base from authorization options in WCF and use that on both java android client and C# winform, also It's necessery to send workspaceId for server.

2- It's important secure data and I have to implant Transport Security or Message Security on server side. How can I develop this feature and used that on java(android) and C#(winform) client.

The solution should be implemented in the IOS Client in future

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like SOAP might be a better option for you here. I would suggest locking things down at the transport level with SSL, and then use `WS-Security` to securely send the username/password in the message header. I would also send the workstation name in the message header as well.